# Windows 8.1 Task Manager Memory usage

Tags: memory, windows-8.1

I know that computer has 4 Gb RAM.

Opened Task Manager and see Memory 36%. For testing (interest) summed up all processes and got 425.1 Mb. 36% is ~ 1/3 of all RAM. But 425.1 * 3 = 1275.3. Video card uses 1 Gb. But in such case question: where is other part of memory? It appears that some processes exists that uses much memory and Task Manager does not inform about that.

Comment: What video card is it? Does it have its own memory?

Comment: Gigabyte GeForce 210 Silent and as understand it has 1 Gb own memory

Comment: Summing up process memory shown by Task Manager won't give you total memory used by processes nor total memory used by system. Some process memory is shared, so total memory taken by processes is smaller than sum of single process values. System allocates some memory for its own purposes (including memory management itself) which is not dedicated for any process.

Comment: So my conclusion is that Windows 8.1 uses ~ 2 Gb for some processes that are not reported in Task Manager....

Comment: Please download RAMMap and run it when you have the high Memory usage. Now save the data as a RMP file. Zip the RMP file and upload the zip to your SkyDrive and post a link here.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2010/08/13/introduction-to-the-new-sysinternals-tool-rammap.aspx