# 100% of RAM is used when the Task Manager shows a cumulative usage of - what should be - less than 12%

Tags: windows-8, memory

I'm only using a limited amount of programs, yet my entire RAM is being used.
These pictures should give enough data. I have also come across [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/694434/windows-8-1-task-manager-memory-usage) so [here is the RAMMap file](https://mega.co.nz/#!hQVjGC6C!BKUsl6IoaVK6U4lK4jwGm7jMe3djCvP6l9NUbn9yAzg) (Mega.co.nz, 102MB).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I believe all the information is in the screenshots.

How is it possible that I'm using 98% of my 8GB RAM with just these processes? How can a less than 200MB Chrome process equal 13% of my memory?

I have also looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/497298/windows-8-task-manager-ram-usage-accuracy) but surely something else must be the case here? I'm at 100%, just Chrome and Visual Studio 2013 shouldn't have such an impact.

Hardware:

- Intel Core i7 4770K
- MSI Z87-GD65
- Sapphire R9 270X Dual-X 2GB GDDR5 OC Boost Lite
- Corsair RM750
- Kingston HyperX Genesis 8 GB DIMM DDR3-1600
- Samsung 840 EVO 250 GB
- 2 hard drives for data (1 x 1TB, 1 x 2TB)

Comment: 5GB into the **Non-Paged Pool**??  I'd take a look into that. Do you have a page file? What kind of hardware do you have?

Comment: @surfasb: I have currently allocated 7652MB in the pagefile. I'll edit my post in a moment with the hardware.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you moved around (large) files across the network prior to this happening then you're at the right address.

The first part of this post is an explanation on how to diagnose this problem and test it yourself but if you just want the solution then you can skip to the end and change the registry entry. Nothing else is needed if you're certain this applies to you.

## The diagnosis

The first thing to do is verify this, ofcourse. You can do this by installing [poolmon](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=317353) through the Windows Developer Kit.

After installing this, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Tools\x64` (change it to 8.0 or x86 if that applies in your case) and start `poolmon.exe`.

Next, press <kbd>P</kbd> to sort by pool type and <kbd>B</kbd> to sort by amount of bytes.

You will now see a screen resembling this:

[image]

You can see that the big issue here is the entry with tag `Wfpn`. If you have this as well then you're at the right post.

The next step is to find out what driver this is related to.

Open the command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and navigate to the drivers folder with

`cd c:\windows\System32\Drivers`

and locate the appropriate driver:

`findstr /s Wfpn *.*`

This should give you something like this:

[image]

We can now see that `netio.sys` is the culprit. After a quick google I came across a thread that discusses (and solves) this problem.

A user diagnosed this problem by booting in safe mode and recognizing that the issue was now solved. This meant that the problem was located in a driver that wasn't loaded. Using elimination it came to light that the [`Ndu.sys` driver](http://batcmd.com/windows/8/services/ndu/) caused this problem.

## The solution

You can disable the driver by starting the registry editor (`regedit.exe`) and navigating to

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Ndu`

and changing the value of "Start" to "4", which will disable it.

[image]

Restart the computer and everything should work fine now (I just transferred 10GB worth of files throughout the network at 10MB/s and my memory usage didn't go beyond 35%).

This post is an accumulated answer from a few sources:

- [Diagnosis of the memory leak's source](https://superuser.com/questions/674649/windows-using-too-much-ram-how-to-diagnose-resource-hog)
- [Diagnosis of the driver and the solution](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/1117499-windows-8-high-memory-usage/)